# Vim: Get Rainbow Parenthesis work with Latexsuite?

Tags: editors, vim

I'm using the text editor vim (or MacVim) together with the LatexSuite plugin. It works good, so far, but there is one thing that annoys me: There is an awesome plugin, Rainbow Parenthesis, that will color matching parenthesis in different colors, which makes spotting unbalanced parentheses very easy.

However, I cannot get it to work properly with LatexSuite, because this package defines a whole bunch of syntax regions that override the regions the rainbow color plugin uses. I get the coloring at the top level, but not after a `\section{Foo}` command, apparently because text below a section becomes a new syntax region...

Did someone succeed in getting these two plugins working together? Or is there a tweaked version of LatexSuite using this type of parenthesis coloring?

Comment: Has this question been answered? Please consider accepting Marcin's answer or supplying your own if you solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin works with AutomaticTexPlugin:
http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/
Note that AutomaticTexPlugin has can close unclosed parenthesis with Tab key.